# Load Multiple files via Snowflake External Tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 50 different filenames (File 1, File 2,....File 50) in AWS S3. All of these files contain different columns.
Do I need to create 50 different External Tables to hold the data for each of these files OR External table is not useful for this use case.

Please advise

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you want to be able to query the data in these files then either you copy it into Snowflake tables or you create external tables. Not really sure what you are asking - are you somehow expecting 50 different datasets to be exposed in 1 external table or possible expecting the process of creating 50 external tables to be automated somehow? Without you explaining what these data files contain and how you expect to use the data, it's difficult for anyone to offer you useful advice

Comment: if each file contains different columns then they are probably better as separate tables...